# camera input capture="environment" not working in webapp

Tags: vue.js, web-applications, camera

Android web app

1. The user sets the front camera mode while using the camera app
2. After entering the web app, click capture="environment" input

this is my code

```
<input
  ref="refPhoto"
  type="file"
  accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png,image/heic"
  name="input_file"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  capture="environment"
  @change="photoInput"
/>
```

3. Front camera exposure, not rear camera